# Using JsonPath to parse JSON String recursively

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jsonpath

I'm trying to parse a given JSON in String format, for example:

```
{
 "id": "indeed",
 "interaction_data":
  "{\"data\":\"{\\\"something\\\":\\\"blabla\\\"}\",\"somethingElseNotNested\":\"Indeed\"}"
}
```

I'm working with Kotlin, and I called JsonPath.parse on the value above, the problem is, `interaction_data` is parsed as a String, instead of it being treated as a JSON as well.

So when I call read("$.interaction_data.data.something") it gives me an error, since interaction_data is treated as a String, instead of an object.

Any way around this? (other than parsing this part separately, I need to handle this generically).

Thanks!

Comment: So... fix the thing that's _generating_ that JSON instead of trying to recursively parse the really weird data it yields? No reason for that thing to stick JSON strings inside JS objects that it then further serializes (i.e. fix the problem, not the symptom.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You're correct, however, this is from legacy code that nobody wants to change, as they like it in String format, probably due to some old legacy MySQL issues.

Comment: So update it to have a _real JSON_ call method too? No need to change existing routes, but at least add something that _you_ need that does the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Json  interaction_data property is triple stringifyied. Why you don't try this

```
var jsonObject=..your json;

 var jsonParsed=JSON.parse(jsonObject.interaction_data);
 jsonParsed.data=JSON.parse(jsonParsed.data);
JsonObject.interaction_data=jsonParsed;
```

result

```
{
"id":"indeed",
"interaction_data":{"data"{"something":"blabla"},"somethingElseNotNested":"Indeed"}
}
```

Comment: Yeah so the issue is that in order to keep the code generic - as we might have a lot of different layouts, I wanted to do it using 1 call to parse then read, so I can keep the path generic (and work without prior knowledge about the internal structure, other than it's a JSON)